# Anchor tag not clickable, clickable area over the <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I've got some HTML structure with CSS

The Anchor tag is located somewhere in the wrapper (doesn't matter that much where) and it's not clickable because of the wrapper Event that's being attached on the div in Angular 4 version, only the wrapper click event fires and not the link Event. No bubbling happening or anything.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" (click)="someFunction()">
  <a (click)="someOtherFunction()"></a>
<div>
```

Comment: You need to stop the propagation or it will trigger only the wrapper. [mdn stop propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: What is expected both events or only anchor tag event?

Comment: I need the <a> tag click event to trigger. But only the wrapper event triggers :(

Answer (score 0):

**Question**: Why both the events are not triggered ..?

**Answer**: Since here you have wrapped div on anchor tag which is a type of ***inline container tag***, and you also have not written any text inside the anchor tag. Which means nothing in div.

Try this:

```
<div class="wrapper" (click)="someFunction()">
  <a (click)="someOtherFunction()">Click Here</a>
<div>
```

- This way when you click on link both the event will be triggered.
- When you click on the area outside of the link only the event attached with div will be triggered.

Comment: I"m sorry, my bad. There is a text in the a tag i somehow forgot to write it in the question. And it still doesn't work with the text. only the wrapper click event triggers but not the link inside the wrapper.

Comment: Try to click on the text written in an anchor tag that will lead to both event triggering. I have tried it.